# Error en mi página HTML, Switch no funciona

Tags: html

¿Cuál es mi error en el código? Al momento de iniciar mi página web me sale en blanco. No entiendo cuál es el error.

```html
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
  <title>Switch</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var
      n1, n2, n3, resultado;
    n1 = prompt('Ingrese un primer valor', ");
        n1 = parseInt(n1); n2 = prompt('ingrese un segundo valor', ");
          n2 = parseInt(n2); n3 = prompt('Ingrese un valor entre el 1 y el 4', ");
            n3 = parseInt(n3);
            switch (n3) {
              case 1:
                resultado = n1 + n2;
                document.write(n1 + '+' + n2 + '=' + resultado);
                break;
              case 2:
                resultado = n1 - n2;
                document.write(n1 + '-' + n2 + '=' + resultado);
                break;
              case 3:
                resultado = n1 * n2;
                document.write(n1 + '*' + n2 + '=' + resultado);
                break;
              case 4:
                resultado = n1 / n2;
                document.write(n1 + '/' + n2 + '=' + resultado);
                break;
              default:
                document.write('debe ingresar un valor comprendido entre 1 y 4.');
            }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

El error se está presentando por `,"` en los `prompt`. También, como consejo, averigua como validar la entrada de datos y el manejo de errores en las conversiones a tipos numéricos.

```html
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
  <title>Switch</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  var n1,n2,n3,resultado;
  // cambios realizados en prompt()
  n1=prompt('Ingrese un primer valor');
  n1=parseInt(n1);
  n2=prompt('ingrese un segundo valor');
  n2=parseInt(n2);
  n3=prompt('Ingrese un valor entre el 1 y el 4');
  n3=parseInt(n3);
  switch(n3){
    case 1: resultado=n1+n2;
            document.write(n1 +'+'+ n2 + '=' + resultado);
            break;
    case 2: resultado=n1-n2;
            document.write(n1 +'-'+ n2 + '=' + resultado);
            break;
    case 3: resultado=n1*n2;
            document.write(n1 +'*'+ n2 + '=' + resultado);
            break;
    case 4: resultado=n1/n2; 
            document.write(n1 +'/'+ n2 + '=' + resultado);
            break;
    default:document.write('debe ingresar un valor comprendido entre 1 y 4.');
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```